# Apply a condition on all but certain columns only for a certain value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to divide all columns (all the months columns -there are way more in the original dataset so I cannot write them manually one by one) but few (Series ID & Country) only when the View Description is Percent change, otherwise keep the values of the other rows as they are.

Input

```
Series ID       View Description       Jan      Feb      Mar   Apr   Country
Food            Percent change         219.98   210.98   205   202   Italy
Drinks          Original Data Value    215.46   205.04   206   203   France
Food at Home    Original Data Value    202.88   203      207   199   Angola
```

I tried two ways with no luck.

1st) for loop with an if statement

```
for i in df1:
        if df1['View Description'] == 'Percent change':
                df1 = df1.set_index(['Series ID', 'View Description', 'Year']).div(100).reset_index()
        else:
```

2nd)

```
cols = ['Series ID', 'View Description']
mask = final_df['View Description'] == 'Percent change'
final_df.loc[mask, final_df.columns != cols] = final_df.loc[mask, final_df.columns != cols].div(100).reset_index()
```

Desired output

```
Series ID       View Description       Jan      Feb      Mar   Apr   Country
Food            Percent change         2.1998   2.1098   2.05  2.02  Italy
Drinks          Original Data Value    215.46   205.04   206   203   France
Food at Home    Original Data Value    202.88   203      207   199   Angola
```

Any suggestions that it can be done more efficiently or even correctly possibly with one of the two methods that I've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unite the analyzes within a single search and do the division, this way you work in detail and can define the specifics:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Series ID': ['Food', 'Drinks', 'Food at Home'],
    'View Description': ['Percent change', 'Original Data Value', 'Original Data Value'],
    'Jan': [219.98, 'B', 'A'],
    'Feb': [210.98, 'B', 'A'],
    'Mar': [205, 'B', 'A'],
    'Apr': [202, 'B', 'A'],
    'Country': ['Italy', 'B', 'A']
})

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']
df.loc[df['View Description'] == 'Percent change', months] /= 100
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Series ID     View Description     Jan     Feb   Mar   Apr Country
0          Food       Percent change  2.1998  2.1098  2.05  2.02   Italy
1        Drinks  Original Data Value       B       B     B     B       B
2  Food at Home  Original Data Value       A       A     A     A       A
```

Note: I left the rest of the values as a string just to confirm that only the desired line would be modified (since divide a string would generate an error).

Comment: It works great, the only issue is that in reality the months columns are 159 and not only that, they keep getting more every month so I have to do that part differently so it basically divides ALL the columns by 100 if the View description == Percent change EXCEPT 3-4 string columns that are fixed and won't change. Any recommendations regarding that?

Comment: @Linear17 to find the best views for this specificity, I advise you to create a new question specifically for this, as you can achieve this result in very different ways and learn from each of them.